# What are the dependencies of the Werewolf games expansions?

Tags: werewolf

I want to buy the party game Werewolf, either "The Werewolves of Millers Hollow" or "Ultimate Werewolf" , but there seems to be different versions and expansions, and the dependencies are unclear for me. Which expansions needs the original game or not, or obsoletes other parts of the game?

- The Werewolves of Millers Hollow

  - Original Game
  - New Moon - *Requires Original Game?*
  - Characters - *Requires Original Game?*
  - The Village - *Standalone? Does it make the other games obsolete?*
  - Special edition - *Standalone? Can it be used in combination with any of the 
    expansions?*
  - *I know there is a big box version that contains many/all expansions. Is this the same as "The Village" or does it contain that and more?*
- Ultimate Werewolf

  - Original Game *(?)*
  - Classic Movie Monsters - *Requires Original Game?*
  - Night Terrors - *Requires Original Game?*
  - Artifacts - *Requires Original Game?*
  - Urban Legends - *Requires Original Game?*
  - Wolfpack - *Requires Original Game?*
  - Deluxe edition - *This is the original game with an expansion? Does it overlap with the other expansions?*

Comment: Based on http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamefamily/2989/werewolf-mafia there are about 100 games that meet your criteria.  Listing them all is not something this site is designed for.

Comment: @bwamer Yes, I see. The intention of my question is to understand the dependencies of the most mainstream/common ones. I have edited my question to concern only this.

Comment: @bwarner, He didn't ask to have them all listed. He asked specific questions about specific version of the game.

Comment: @PaulMag, Why don't you visit the pages of these games on BGG, find the majority of your answers, and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: This question is no longer Too Broad. You may not enjoy the tedious task of researching and writing up the dependencies for a set of thirteen games, but that is not a valid reason to close the question. The question as currently written is absolutely answerable in a tiny amount of space. The OP thinks that a single question with thirteen games is better than thirteen questions with a single game, and that's *his* prerogative.

Comment: @ikegami The website BGG answered my questions, thanks! I had seen it before, but did not realise until now that it actually lists all dependencies and reimplementations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found almost all the answers on [boardgamegeek.com](http://boardgamegeek.com/). That page is very handy for this purpose.

- The Werewolves of Millers Hollow

  - The Werewolves of Millers Hollow - *Original Game*
  - The Village - *Expansion which also contains Original Game.*
  - New Moon - *Requires Original Game (or The Village)*
  - Characters - *Requires Original Game (or The Village)*
  - Special edition - *It is standalone. Found no more info.*
  - The Werewolves of Miller's Hollow: The Pact - *Contains: Original Game + The Village + New Moon + Characters (so full game with all expansions)*
- Ultimate Werewolf

  - "Ultimate Werewolf" / "Werewolf" - *Original Game*
  - Ultimate Werewolf: Whitebox edition - *Reimplements Original Game*
  - Ultimate Werewolf: Ultimate edition - *Reimplements Whitebox Edition*
  - Ultimate Werewolf: Deluxe edition - *Reimplements Ultimate Edition*
  - Classic Movie Monsters - *Requires Original Game (or one of the reimplementations)*
  - Night Terrors - *Requires Original Game (or one of the reimplementations)*
  - Artifacts - *Requires Original Game (or one of the reimplementations)*
  - Urban Legends - *Requires Original Game (or one of the reimplementations)*
  - Wolfpack - *Requires Original Game (or one of the reimplementations)*
  - Ultimate Werewolf: Deluxe Edition For Kickstarter - *Contains: Deluxe Edition +  Classic Movie Monsters + Night Terrors + Urban Legends + Wolfpack (NOT Artifacts)*

Comment: I'm a frequent moderator. +1 to this.

Comment: Did you mean the Pact for the last pack for the Werewolf of Millers Hollow?

Comment: @AxelAdvento YES! After over 4 years that was finally cleared up. I have, however, played quite a bit of Ultimate Werewolf these years. :)